# Give diferent className to MenuProps and Parent Select Componens with styled-components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I'm trying to customize a MUI TextField Select component with styled components.

The ideia is styled-compoents provide diferent classes to Select field and Menu, so i can have their styled separated.

```
const StyledSelect = styled(({ className, ...props }) => {
    return (
        <TextField {...props}
            classes={{ root: className }}
            SelectProps={{
                MenuProps: {
                    classes: { paper: className, list: className },
                    anchorOrigin: {
                        vertical: "bottom",
                        horizontal: "left"
                    },
                    transformOrigin: {
                        vertical: "top",
                        horizontal: "left"
                    },
                    getContentAnchorEl: null
                },
            }}
        />
    )
})`
    & {
      background-color: #454D5D;
      border-radius: 10px;
      margin-top: 5px;
    }
    & li {
        color: #FFF;
    }
    &.MuiFormControl-root {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    & .MuiListItem-root {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    & .MuiListItem-root.Mui-selected {
        background-color: #1A2233;
    }
    & .MuiFormLabel-root {
        font-family: 'Roboto';
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    & .MuiInputLabel-shrink {
        color: ${props => props.color};
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    & .MuiInput-underline:after {
        border-bottom: 2px solid ${props => props.errors[props.field.name] && props.touched[props.field.name]
        ? CASABLANCA : props.color};
        transition: none;
        transform: none;
    }
    & .MuiInput-underline:before {
        border-bottom: 1px solid ${props => props.color}
    }
    & .MuiSelect-roo {
        color: black;
        font-family: 'Roboto';
        font-weight: 300;
    }  
    & .MuiSelect-select:focus {
        background: transparent;
    }
  `;
```

I wish my TextField class would be different from MenuProps class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to have one wrapper component per class name you need to generate. In my example below, `StyledTextField` takes care of the root class name for `TextField` (the `className` property [is equivalent to classes.root](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.3.1/packages/material-ui/src/TextField/TextField.js#L148)) and then `MenuPaperClass` provides an additional class name.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)`
  /* && to add specificity */
  && {
    border: 1px solid green;
  }
`;

const MenuPaperClass = styled(({ className, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <StyledTextField
      SelectProps={{ MenuProps: { classes: { paper: className } } }}
      value="1"
      select
      {...props}
    >
      <MenuItem value="1">One</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="2">Two</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="3">Three</MenuItem>
    </StyledTextField>
  );
})`
  && {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
`;
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MenuPaperClass />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit styled-components multiple classes]

This isn't a particularly elegant solution and gets pretty tedious if you have 3 or more separate classes you want to use, so I may come back to this later to consider alternative approaches/syntax, but this does work.